# Drag and Drop cell between different Collection Views

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have multiple collection views on one screen

In  collectionView One i have normal cell like Square
In  collectionView two i have group cell e.g same cell but multiple surrounded by a border of Group

I need to Enable Drag and Drop between One Collection View to Another.

[image: POC Snap Shot Attached here]

I am using swift 3.0.

Comment: Is there any reason for the two different collectionViews? Why not use just one with multiple sections

Comment: Ok. What have you tried so far and what didn't work?

Comment: @luk2302,  I Initially thought that, but the problem being i want the Group to also be Draggable and Also  the Cell, so would i need to control collection view inside collection view?

Answer (score 5):

You can use this one from GitHub:

https://github.com/mmick66/KDDragAndDropCollectionView

[image]

And here is a nice guide for it:

http://blog.karmadust.com/drag-and-drop-between-uicollectionviews/

Comment: thank, but thats not exactly what i need. i have a group in second collection view which is draggable. also i am using swift 3 /

Answer (score 2):

Drag from collectionView2:

- Create an independent and drag-able instance of the cell with the same data and place it above the cell to drag
- In Collectionview2, set the `cell.isHidden = yes`. This way the cell is not visible, but its empty space remains.
- When the drag-able cell is significant dragged away from the original position, remove the original cell from the collectionView animated.

Drag to collectionView1:

When the drag-able cell is above collectionView1 and is dropped:

- insert (animated) a cell to the target position in collectionView1 and set it hidden
- move drag-able cell above the inserted (but hidden) cell
- set target cell to `isHidden = false`
- remove drag-able cell from superview

Comment: The issue is , in  the image as i showed, i need the cell and group both be draggable and droppable.

Comment: The Group has different view and cell has diffferent and to make cell draggable and droppable inside a group i require to put collection view inside the collection view? if i do so : how would i be able to move cell from one group to another?